# Consume Spring WebFlux APIs in next JS

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, next.js, spring-webflux

We have implemented REST APIs using Spring WebFlux. I have two questions regarding this APIs.

1. Our UI application developed using react and next JS has to consume them. Does the way UI should consume these APIs differ from the normal REST APIs? If possible, please share any example.
2. From backend perspective alone, how can I validate that these APIs are more efficient than the normal REST APIs? I want to see the difference it makes to the performance.

Thank you.